# mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching id = 'polls_form_25' while filling out form with mechanize

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, mechanize, mechanize-python

Basically what the title says. I'm trying to automatically fill out a form containing radio buttons, but I keep getting this error from line 7.

```
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching id = 'polls_form_25'
```

Here's the raw code.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; 
rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open("http://www.danpatrick.com/meatbracket/")
br.form.find_control(id="polls_25_ans").value = 'poll_25'
br.submit()
```

I've run the code below to try to find available forms, but I get `'None'`

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; 
rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open("http://www.danpatrick.com/meatbracket/")
for form in br.forms():
    print(form.name)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the site just blocking robot requests past what I've already got around? If so, how would I get past that?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code?  The error in the title says that it can't find `polls_form_25`, but the code appears to be looking for `polls-25-ans`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oops. Little mistake that I made while copying the source code. From the HTML, I see that the form should be `polls_form_25` and the answer's html is `<input type="radio" id="poll-answer-54" name="poll_25" value="54">`